# Go get behaving erratically during build and with VScode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, build

Using Go version `go1.17.1 linux/amd64` on my CentOS 7. `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` are set in my `.bashrc` in the order:

```
export GOPATH="${HOME}/.go"
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
export PATH="$PATH:${GOPATH}/bin:${GOROOT}/bin"
```

Got my project in `/home/wsb/_projects/local/parlance`:

```
[wsb@localhost local]$ pwd
/home/wsb/_projects/local
[wsb@localhost local]$ tree
.
└── parlance/
    └── main.go
    └── utils.go
```

From the terminal, using `go get` stores src in `/home/wsb/.go/pkg/mod/cache...` folder

```
[wsb@localhost parlance]$ go get -v -u github.com/gorilla/mux
go: downloading github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
github.com/gorilla/mux
    
[wsb@localhost parlance]$ go build main.go 
main.go:3:8: no required module provides package github.com/gin-gonic/gin: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
[wsb@localhost parlance]$ 
    
[root@localhost /]# find -iname gin
./home/wsb/.go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

Why would it throw error on build?

Comment: _“go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory;”_, plus you are only building one file instead of the package, just use `go build`

Answer (score 1):

Using `go mod` is the key here for managing packages for any particular projects.

`go mod` is used for installing and tracking external packages outside of packages in `GOPATH`.

From within existing project root directory `parlance` we initialize `go mod` using:

```
[wsb@localhost parlance]$ go mod parlance
```

It creates two files within the project root directory: `go.mod` and `go.sum`.

Now we can `go get` any module we will use specifically for our project.

```
go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
go get github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2
```

This creates external package requirement details in `go.mod` and their respective checksum in `go.sum` file.

Finally, we can build/run our package like

```
go build main.go    
go run main.go
```